# （a linear algebra exercise）Pricipal minors for a matrix where all off-diagonal entries are negative

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $n$ be a positive integer and $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a matrix that satisfies:

1. All the leading principal minors are positive;
2. All the off-diagonal entries are negative.

Prove that all the principal minors of $A$ are positive.

I have a very indirect solution to this problem, which involves taking the inverse of $A$, proving that all the entries of $A^{-1}$ are positive by induction, and then using this result to prove the positivity of all principal minors via another induction. I'm still looking for a direct approach that works.

In fact, if we change the conditions to:

1. All the leading principal minors are *non-negative*.
2. All the off-diagonal entries are negative.

the aforementioned solution would fail, since $A^{-1}$ might not exist.

Comment: Why not share your approach, so that we can see the approach you've already followed?

Comment: The idea should be simple, when you expand a leading  principle minor along a raw, you get a sum of a leading minor and as negative minors the rest (here there is an induction reason) so if the leading minor is positive the principle minors should be also positive.

Comment: @Toni Mhax I don't think the solution would be that simple. If you expand along a row that is not the last row, you cannot get a leading minor in your sum.

Comment: let us say you expand the determinant n minor depending on which row you expend you get a sum of a principal minor and the rest minors should be negative and so on for each principle minor we can write it etc verify

Comment: @Toni Mhax Why are the rest minors negative? I can't see why this is obvious

Comment: It is not obvious but  i took an exemple and it seems to work the easy say $n=3$ , $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&-b&-c\\-d&e&-f\\-k&-r&l\end{pmatrix}$ where all variables are positive. $\det(A)>0$ expanding the first row $$a(el-rf)+b(-dl-kf)-c(dr+ke)$$ am i missing that the diagonal could be negative?

Comment: @Toni Mhax Yeah, it is indeed easy with $n=3$, but it seems to be harder for a general integer $n$. Even for $n=4$ I tried and failed to see why it works. The non-principal minors in the sum seem to be a lot more chaotic.